# Is it possible to suppress upstream DNS records with dnsmasq

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

Using dnsmasq, I can set new values for existing records, and add new records, event to a zone I don't own. But is it possible to mask or suppress an existing record ?

In my case I want a CNAME to be non existent and return status NXDOMAIN

I tried

```
cname=unwanted.example.org,
```

But dnsmasq would'nt start. I then tried

```
cname=unwanted.example.org,_
```

As this is ignored, I get the real CNAME record from the real DNS servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
address=/unwanted.example.org/
```

> --address=/example.com/ is equivalent to --server=/example.com/ and returns NXDOMAIN for example.com and all its subdomains.